# NodeJS and node-serialport i'm having trouble writing

Tags: node.js, serial-port, node-serialport

I'm having trouble sending a command to an RFID-reader over a RS232 serial connection. I can connect to the reader and write messages to it but i'm not getting any response.

In the [documentation](http://www.sebeto.com/intranet/ftpscambio/RFID_FEIG/Readers/ID%20ISC%20SPAD102/Documentation/H01113-0e-ID-B.pdf) of the reader I can find a possible explanation for this problem(p. 16):

*There is no reply from the reader if there is a protocol frame failure.*

The following information is available for the protocol frame format:

[image]

So that's `0x02 0x00 0x09 0x00 0xB0 0x01 0x00 0xCA 0x86` in hex for the inventory(getting all the tags in range) command.

I'm 100% sure that the reader works and the serial settings are correct but I'm not sure I'm using the Buffer in the correct way.

This is what I have as code at the moment:

**settings.json**

```
{
  "serialport":"COM3",
  "baudrate":38400
}
```

**app.js**

```
var settings = require('./settings');
var serialport= require('serialport');
var SerialPort = serialport.SerialPort;

var inventorycommand = new Buffer([0x02,0x00,0x09,0x00,0xB0,0x01,0x00,0xCA,0x86],'hex');

var serialconnection = new SerialPort(settings.serialport,{baudRate:settings.baudrate,parity:'even',encoding:'hex'},false);

serialconnection.open(portOpened);

function portOpened(err) {
    if(err)console.log('ERR: '+ err);
    console.log('serial port opened: '+ settings.serialport+' with baudrate '+ settings.baudrate);

    setTimeout(function(){
        serialconnection.write(inventorycommand.toString('hex'));
        console.log(inventorycommand.toString('hex'));
    },1000);


    serialconnection.on('data',dataReceived);
    serialconnection.on('close', portClosed);
    serialconnection.on('error',errorReceived);

    function dataReceived(data) {
        console.log('data received: ' +data);
    }

    function portClosed() {
        console.log('port closed.')
    }

    function errorReceived(err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like adding the callback function to the `write()` function call fixed the problem.

```
serialconnection.write(inventorycommand,function(err,result){
            if(err){
                console.log('ERR: ' + err);
            }
            console.log('result:' + result)
        });
```